# Block calls on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I know this question has been asked many times, but with this code:

```
static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {

NSString *notifyname = (__bridge NSString *)name;

if ([notifyname isEqualToString:@"kCTCallIdentificationChangeNotification"]) {

    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary *)userInfo;
    CTCall *call = (__bridge CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
    NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
    NSLog(@"RECEIVED CALL: %@", caller);
    CTCallDisconnect(call);

}
```

i see 1 second of call((
How to make sure that it was not and it working as iBlacklist?

Comment: can you reformulate your question ?

Comment: I want my program to block calls, but with that code i still see blocked call for a second

Comment: I have no clue what you are really trying to ask. Please clarify or reformulate your question, as @Gossamer suggested, otherwise it is going to get downvoted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm find solution - need use hook from MobileSubstrate. I find sample code in [blocking calls and sms](https://github.com/shyang/cate)

P.S. sorry for my English((